# How to save a django model into json file

Tags: json, django

I would like to save a Django model into a json file into a specific directory. How can I do that? My code is below in views.py.

```
def JSON(request):
with open(r'C:\Users\Savas\Desktop\DOCUMENTS\file.json', "w") as out:
    mast_point = serializers.serialize("json", Poi.objects.all())
    out.write(mast_point)
```

Comment: you code is already doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Good morning!

did you look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) for this? :)

Additionally i would suggest that you indent you code like the following:

```py
from django.core import serializers
from .models import yourmodel
from django.http import HttpResponse

def example(request):
    objects = yourmodel.objects.all()
    with open(r'...your path...\file.json', "w") as out:
        mast_point = serializers.serialize("json", objects)
        out.write(mast_point)
    template = loader.get_template('some_template.html')
    context = {'object': objects}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I just tried this code snippet and it worked in my sample django application, of course you have to adapt this snippet a little bit :)

Comment: Good evening! Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried it but it didn't work. It is most probably because I am receiving an error of "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'". I am tackling with this error right now. As soon as I solve this error I will try again your suggestion.

Comment: sounds good! did you look in your model config, maybe the problem is hidden there and there is passend into the json serialize function?

Answer (score 3):

As of version 1.1 and greater, the Django dumpdata management command allows you to dump data from individual tables:

```
./manage.py dumpdata myapp2.my_model > fixtures/file_name.json
```